# Making a counter that goes from 1 to 6

Tags: counter, 7segmentdisplay

How do I make a counter that goes from 1 to 6? I have a 555 Timer connected to a 74LS390N counter which is connected to a 7 segment display module.

I can't figure out how to make the counter's output start from 0001 and end at 0110 and then go back to 0001.

Currently:

DCBA     Number

0000     0

0001     1

.

.

.

1001     9

0000     0

Comment: Do you want to add stuff to this circuit, or do you want to change components to ones which are more suitable?

Comment: add stuff @pipe

Answer (score 1):

A decade counter isn't particularly suited for this type of task. The 74LS390N does have a "CLR" pin, which makes the output immediately back to 0000, but this doesn't do much good, as you want 0001. You could make some clever tricks with additional logic, but that wouldn't be easy, and it isn't a flexible option in general.

Tasks like this are generally done with a microcontroller. It would replace the 555, the '390 and the associated circuitry around them, and gives you flexibility as an added bonus.

Answer (score 1):

The 74390 counter doesn't provide any way of resetting to a predefined value: it resets to zero, and cannot be made to reset to anything else.

Ideally, you'd need to use a counter with a preset option (e.g. a [74xx160](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC160.pdf) -- although as you're currently use an LS range component you'd want either a 74LS160 or a 74HCT160, not the 74HC160 in the datasheet I linked to), but you indicated that you'd rather solve the problem by adding additional components rather than changing what you already have, so an alternative solution would be to use a 4-bit adder (e.g. a [74xx283](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/NXP%20PDFs/74HC283.pdf)) to increase the output count by 1, and change your counter's reset behaviour to reset when it reaches 6 rather than 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can do n-1 counting by generating an extra clock pulse by using an exclusive or gate. For instance if you wanted to divide by 7, feed the clock via the exor and then feedback the divide by 8 output to the other exor gate input. When 1000 arrives it causes a double clock pulse to appear that rapidly forces it through the unwanted state of 1000...

So, reset the chip when 7 is detected (using a regular 3 input OR gate). This rapidly unresets the chip (because 7 is no longer detected). Now you have 0000. If you now detect 0000 with a NOR gate you can feed this into the exor gate to count an extra pulse that rapidly brings you through 0000 to 0001.

It's not perfect because it creates momentary occurrences of 0111 and 0000 but may be fine for some circuits. FPGA designers please look-away!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the counter resets on the rising edge, why not use the clock as your LSB:

```
(0001) where the LSB is the clock and resets @ 3 (0110)
 ^^^^                                             ^^^^
 321C                                             321C
```

Comment: That took me half a minute to understand but it appears an interesting trick. I presume "rests" should be "resets". (That must have been 25 s of the 30.) Isn't there a problem after reset that the outputs will be (0001) followed by (0000)?

Comment: Yes should be 'resets'.  I use this trick from time to time.

Comment: What about the other bit?